# I need plugin or method suggestion

Tags: plugins

I am trying to help a local entrepreneurship society to add a feature to our website where people who want to build a team around a business idea could post their project description with contact details so that it will be shown on the website for visitors.

We have WordPress with Elementor, any idea or suggestion on how we could accomplish this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This his how I would do it.
Create a page with a form for the user to input their info, title, body text...
then with code make that form info create a post with a category only for this.
finnaly just show this on your page, or have a specific page to show this posts only.

Using only elementor, its possible to create the page form, and in the beginning add a custom shortcode that gets the form info and create the post.
To give here the shortcode code to insert into functions.php only having the form values.